# How to protect video from download Vimeo

Tags: security, vimeo, vimeo-api, drm, vimeo-player

Some online resources recommended Vimeo as a video hosting platform. My aim is to have my videos hosted and **protected** from being downloaded by any mean (including the download extensions or plugins like).

I'm in the trial version of the Plus plan. I was able to set video privacy as private and using the API I was able to get the video but once I got the video on the screen I was able to download it super easy with Internet Download Manager plugin.

Is Vimeo capable of protecting the video from download?
Is there other video hosting service that is able to host and protect the video from being downloaded?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a customer support question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Vimeo and they don't have option to protect the video from downloading in the way I mentioned. And I guess most of the competitors are the same unless they clearly market they offer DRM support.

Here is a snippet from their reply to me:

------------ Vimeo Reply -----------

Unfortunately, online video distribution is inherently insecure in this way and no form of protection or security has 100% fared against the might of online piracy. We are always working to improve the security of our player, but as technology grows and users become savvier, the inevitable reality is that online videos are becoming less secure.

Some solutions for preventing unauthorized downloads include DRM or file encryption, which are features we do not currently offer for Vimeo members. Advanced techniques like DRM would substantially increase the cost of hosting your videos, and we want Vimeo to be as affordable as possible to as many people as possible.

---